# How to activate matplotlib 1.4

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

on Ubuntu I installed Anaconda3-2.1.0-Linux-x86_64, works fine however the version 1.4.2 is not activated in python, how can I activate it ?

```
pip freeze
matplotlib==1.4.2
```

python in a shell

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.2.1'
```

ipython

```
In [1]: import matplotlib
In [2]: matplotlib.__version__
Out[2]: '1.4.2'
```

paths

```
which python
/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python

which ipython
/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/ipython
```

I tried to create a virtual environment with 
    conda create -n py34 matplotlib=1.4.2

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    ....
    matplotlib: 1.4.2-np19py34_0
    ....
```

pip is at least consistent with python in the environment

```
(py34)pip freeze
matplotlib==1.2.1
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `pip is at least consistent with python in the environment`? Did you install pip via  `conda install pip`?

Comment: @cel I mean that in the environment the library version in python is the same than the one given by pip. Outside environment pip says matplotlib version 1.4.2 , python says 1.2.1

Comment: Have you tried `print(matplotlib)` right after importing? The printed path may help to find the culprit.

Comment: @cel seems you have the point, in ipython the path is '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py', in python this is '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py', do you know how to change the path?

Comment: I don't have a concrete idea. You could check `site.getsitepackages()` what paths are searched for third-party packages.

Comment: @cel thanks for help, I set PYTHONPATH to the correct directory, but I have other errors now when importing matplotlib, will probably re-install all.

Comment: Ideally you should not have PYTHONPATH set at all. Having it set will mess up your conda environments (it will make them all point to the path in your PYTHONPATH, regardless of which one is active).